# How to get the time varying coefficients using dlmFilter in dlm package on R?

Tags: r, optimization, model, forecasting, kalman-filter

I've tried to use dlm package on R to forecast with Kalman Filter.

My model is like this, using five variables:

```
build <- function(u) {
  reg <-dlmModReg(vars[,1:5], start=startM, end=endM, dV=exp(u[1]), dW=exp(u[2:7]))
  return(reg)
}
```

I can get time varying coefficients when MODELING. However, when I try to forecast, the coefficients in the result gets constant only in the forecasting part like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/boig4ln5acxrtra/coefficients.png

I use the following way to predict.

Gaussian state space forecasting with regression effects
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/gaussian-state-space-forecasting-with-regression-effects

So, if anyone know how to get time-varying coefficients in dlmFilter to forecast, please let me know. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the book by Giovanni Petris http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387772370